# Promise returns a wrong type when accessing firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

When the user enters the page, I want to check if the user has already put in data to a firebase location. I use this code for this purpose:

(Within the Provider:)

```
checkPath():  Promise<boolean> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.database().ref('/Data')
        .child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child("dataID")
        .on('value', data => {
            resolve(data.exists());
        });
    });  
    }
```

(Within the page:)

```
ionViewDidEnter() {

  if(this.Provider.checkPath() === true) {

//Here I retrieve data from firebase

  }
}
```

But now the following Error occurs:

> `Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`

My first question is: was I right when using a Promise to check whether there is data from the user? In my opinion one needs a promise because otherwise the Page will do its things, but it could be that the data isn't loaded.

The second question is: how do I get a boolean out of the promises return to check if data is in the location? Or do you have any other solution to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

First things first, the error you are getting is due to the latest `TypeScript` version. They require that you specify in your `new Promise<T>` statement what the return type of this `Promise` is going to be:

```
checkPath():  Promise<boolean> { 
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.database().ref('/Data')
        .child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child("dataID")
        .on('value', data => {
            resolve(data.exists());
        });
    });  
}
```

Second point is, you can't check your Promise return like that. You should use the await/async from TypeScript (which I prefer):

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.checkPath();
}

async checkPath(): Promise<void> {
     if((await this.Provider.checkPath()) === true) {
          //Here I retrieve data from firebase 
    }
}
```

Or use basic Promise handling:

```
this.Provider.checkPath().then((result: boolean) => {
   if (result) {
       //Here I retrieve data from firebase
   }
})
```

Actually, I read your question correctly now, and the first thing I said is not what's causing your error. That's definitely all because you are trying to compare a `Promise` with a `boolean`. Doesn't mean that you shouldn't do the first thing anyways :)

Comment: Understood. I changed the types of the promises. When you say "basic Promise handling" do you mean something like @atomrc mentioned in the answer below? I am very new to coding, so forgive my stupidness.

Comment: Yes indeed. You can use `then()`. But do not use the `function` keyword, because this messes up the `this` context. You should use arrow notation: `() => {}`. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: After correcting another stupid mistake (which was about retrieving the data) it works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is that you are directly comparing the returned promise with a boolean we you do `Provider.checkPath() === true`.

As a promise is simply a wrapper for a value, in order to get the value contained in the promise (in your case the boolean) you need to use the `then` method.

The code would look like that

```
this.Provider.checkPath().then(function (value) {
  // 'value' is your boolean
})
```

BTW, yes, using a `Promise` was a very good idea, this is exactly the use case for them :)

Comment: That makes sense. I did it like this now : `ionViewDidEnter() {
 
    this.szenarioProvider.checkPath().then(function (value) {
  
  if(value === true) {
  
//retrieve Data here
  } 
 });
    }`  But it throws `Cannot read property 'szenarioProvider' of undefined TypeError`

Comment: The full Error message is: `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'szenarioProvider' of undefined`

Comment: As @PierreDuc stated in the answer above, I had to use the arrow function. Nevertheless: thank you!